# A converse theorem for Hecke modular forms?

Tags: gamma-function, modular-forms, dirichlet-series

Let $f$ be a function which can be represented by a Dirichlet serie (for $\Re s$ big enough)
$$f(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{a(n)}{n^s}}$$
and which can be meromorphically extend to $\mathbb{C}$ by the functionnal equation
$$\frac{f(s)\Gamma(s)}{(2\pi)^s}=\frac{f(k-s)\Gamma(k-s)}{(2\pi)^{k-s}}$$
Can I conclude that it exists $a(0)$ such that
$$F(\tau)=a(0)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a(n)e^{2i\pi n \tau}}$$
is a modular form of weight $k$ on the full modular group ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is more or less yes. You need $F$ to be holomorphic on the upper half plane, and for the coefficients to have polynomial growth: $a(n)=O(n^r)$ for some $r>0$. There is also a condition on the poles of completed $L$-function, which determines $a_0$. This is consequence of Hecke's converse theorem.

See for example, corollary 3.2 in these notes: 
http://www.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/seminars/ws0607/modular-forms/Heckes_converse_theorem.pdf

Comment: Thanks a lot ! But the fact that $a(n)=\mathcal{O}(n^r)$ should garantee the holomorphy of $F$ in the upper half plane, shouldn't it ? (I don't know if my sentence is correct, I'm a french user... :p )